# How to calculate the variance of a continuous distribution function but with a mass point?

Tags: variance

I have a continuous distribution function, but it has a mass point at the upper bound, say with a probability of p>0. How to calculate its variance?

Answer (score 0):

If $b$ is the upper bound then the variance is $\int x^{2} f(x)\, dx-(\int f(x) \, dx)^{2}+b^{2}p-bp$ where $f$ is the density up to $b$.

Comment: Thanks, do you mind providing a derivation?

Comment: When you calculate the second moment you integrate over $\{b\}$ and then over the remaining part. This gives $b^{2}p+\int x^{2}f(x) \, dx$. Similarly you can write down the first moment and then calculate the variance.

Comment: No, I don't think this is right. Something is wrong in your formula.